# Sequelize how to convert a complex raw query to Sequelize query

Tags: sequelize.js

I've this raw SQL query.

```
SELECT 
    restaurants.name AS restaurant,
    ROUND((6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(6.9271)) * COS(RADIANS(restaurants.latitude)) *
    COS(RADIANS(restaurants.longitude) - RADIANS(79.8612)) + SIN(RADIANS(6.9271)) *
    SIN(RADIANS(restaurants.latitude)))),
            2) AS distance,
    dishes.price
FROM
    restaurants
        INNER JOIN
    dishes ON restaurants.id = dishes.restaurantId
WHERE
    restaurants.status = TRUE
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 200;
```

I do want to convert this query to a Sequelize query.
What I've done upto now is

```
const data = await db.restaurant.findAll({
      attributes: ['name'],
      include: [{ model: db.dish, attributes: ['price'] }],
      where: {
        status: true,
      },
      limit: 200,
    });
```

How do I add this **distance** thing to my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sequelize.literal()` to include the haversine distance -

```
attributes: [
  'name',
  [sequelize.literal(`
    ROUND((6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(6.9271)) * COS(RADIANS(restaurants.latitude)) *
    COS(RADIANS(restaurants.longitude) - RADIANS(79.8612)) + SIN(RADIANS(6.9271)) *
    SIN(RADIANS(restaurants.latitude)))), 2)
  `, 'distance'],
],
```